# How to connect our Jira using nodejs

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm beginner in this territory! 
My question is how to connect to our Jira ( https://mycompany.atlassian.net (cloud)) for get all data from our jira projects (ex. user stories, tasks, issues ...).
 - I have access to admin jira !
 - I saw this: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/
 - Should I have to buy an another licence for access to get data from api?

What are the first steps?

Comment: There is this project in Github that can help you: https://github.com/steves/node-jira, but you will need some understanding about NodeJS to make it happen. Maybe take some time to make a initial program in node to then interact with the API. About the license, I don't believe you need to pay for anything else. The REST API is just a programatically way provided to access the information from Jira. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the license you purchased to use Jira gives you access to the api without further cost.

*First steps?*

The second link you gave in your post relating to the api (docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/) gives you everything you need to know if you understand its content. 
Googling `nodejs jira api` gave a number of package results that would make interacting with the api very easy. At the time [node-jira](https://github.com/steves/node-jira) was top of the list and looked like it suited your needs. There are other packages too so worth looking around.

### General pointers:

1. Start on a list of nodejs packages you will need to build your app from what you know and package searches. Initialize your node project and start adding those packages to package.json.
2. Identify the Jira authentication method you are going to use.

   - The api supports basic over https or oauth and cookie once authenticated.
   - Find examples of how the package you are using handles authentication. It should be easy in the package readme or with google.
3. Identify the API calls that will give you the data you need.

   - The options are easy to find in node-jira readme if using it or use the api docs.
   - The jira api documentation will give you the expected json response schema that you will need to access the json you get back.
   - An example would be the [Projects](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/project-getAllProjects) api definition. It gives you an example response and the full response schema.
   - The api options are described as 'expandable' which means you only get what you ask for, if you want more you have to ask for it. (see expand option for each api call)
4. Consider what you need to process the data you get back and display it in whatever format you require.

   - Again more package options, json processing, templating.
   - If it is a web page you might need something like express.
5. Use that information to start coding (not in any specific order).

   - Code for getting requests (say a web page).
   - Code for authentication and api calls.
   - Code for templating each data view of api response data.
   - Code the overall app structure.
   - Give yourself some debug messages that can be turned on and off so you can see process sequence which can help a lot in troubleshooting.
6. Write test scripts! Change code.... run the test/s, got a new feature... write a test then code to the test. Retest before release.

There are lots of package options, information, and examples. Use Google lots, search npmjs.com for packages, use the api docs.